When creating a host pool in Azure Virtual Desktop, does it automatically know when there are multiple replicas available?
I've been trying to figure out why deploying an AVD host pool with 125 session hosts times out typically leaving none registered and often fewer than 125 created.
I don't have a great deal of configuration applied to the image I'm using. It is the basic Win10 22H2 Gen2 offering from the Azure Marketplace. I add seven or eight small applications and drivers (7-zip, Git for Windows, VS Code, PIV drivers), enable nested virtualization and remove unnecessary applications using the Virtual Desktop Optimization Tool. It isn't overloaded by any stretch and this issue has occurred even with none of the above applied to the basic image.
I recently saw something that I hadn't prior which is the recommendation of one replica per 20 hosts being deployed. Too few replicas can overtax them leading to throttling and timeouts eventually leading to failure of the deployment.
I've looked but haven't seen anything about how the replicas are handled. Do I need to set up my process to know there are multiple replicas or does the backend know to look for them and distribute the load accordingly?
